# Use of the '<' operator in SAS

Tags: sas

I have to convert some SAS code. In other programming languages I am used to < being used in comparisons e.g. in pseudo-code: `If x < y then z`

In SAS, what is the < operator achieving here:

`intck(month,startdate,enddate)-(day(enddate)<day(startdate))`

I have been able to understand the functions using the reference documentation but I can't see anything relating to how '<' is being used here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to go into a little more detail about what the code you have there is doing, it's an old school method to determine the number of months from one date to the next (possibly to calculate a birthday, for example).

Originally, SAS functions `intck` and `intnx` only calculated the number of "firsts of the month" in between two dates (or similar for other intervals).  So `INTCK('month','31OCT2020'd, '01NOV2020'd) = 1`, while `INTCK('month','01OCT2020'd,'30NOV2020'd) = 1`.  Not ideal!  So you'd add in this particular bit of code, `-(day(enddate)<day(startdate))`, which says "if it is not been a *full* month yet, subtract one".  It's equivalent to this:

```
if day(enddate) < day(startdate) then diff = intck(month,startdate,enddate) - 1;
else diff = intck(month,startdate,enddate);
```

There's now a better way to do this (yay!).  [`intck`](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lefunctionsref/p1md4mx2crzfaqn14va8kt7qvfhr.htm) and ['intnx'](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lefunctionsref/p10v3sa3i4kfxfn1sovhi5xzxh8n.htm) are a bit different, but it's the same idea.  For `intck` the argument is `method`, where `c` for "continuous" is what you want to compare same period in the month.  For `intnx` it is the `alignment` option, where `'s'` means "same" (so, move to the same point in the month).

So your code now should be:

```
intck(month,startdate,enddate,'c')
```

Answer (score 3):

The symbol `<` is an **operator** in that expression.  It is not a **function** call , like INTNX() is in your expression.

SAS evaluates boolean expressions (like the less than test in your example) to 1 for TRUE and 0 for FALSE.

So your expression is subtracting 1 when the day of month of ENDDATE is smaller than the day of month of STARTDATE.

Note:  You can also do the reverse, treat a number as a boolean expression. For example in a statement like:

```
if (BASELINE) then PERCENT_CHANGE = (VALUE-BASELINE) / BASELINE ;
```

A missing value or a value of zero in BASELINE will be treated as FALSE and so in those cases the assignment statement does not run.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which was useful. I think the other answer I've now accepted is slightly more beneficial if other users came across similar code and needed to understand exactly what it was doing.